# MetaTrader 4 / MQL4 Time is off by -5 hours but only when using epoc time

Tags: time, epoch, mql4, metatrader4

I'm working with MetaTrader4 running in WINE in Ubuntu 16.04. I have a simple inline function that saves the time and various other info to a file using this line:

```
FileWrite(data_filehandle, "sys_time:" + (string)TimeLocal() + "." + StringFormat("%06lu", usec_instance) + ", sym:" + (string)Symbol() + ", tick_time:" + (string)last_tick.time + ", ask:" + (string)last_tick.ask + ", bid:" + (string)last_tick.bid);
```

Using the directive:

```
#property strict
```

will cause it to output the time in a Date Time format.
Removing that directive will cause it to output time in epoc format.

When it uses Date Time format ( by using '#property strict' ), the time is correct.

It outputs:

```
sys_time:2020.01.21 07:38:02.994394, sym:EURUSD, tick_time:2020.01.21 14:38:03, ask:1.1104, bid:1.1103
```

This matches my system time correctly.

Now if I remove '#property strict' to switch to epoc time

It outputs:

```
sys_time:1579592538.630395, sym:EURUSD, tick_time:1579617738, ask:1.1105, bid:1.11041
```

my local time is:

```
$ date '+%s'
1579610544

$ date '+%Z %z'
EST -0500
```

my time: 1579610544 - MT4 LocalTime: 1579592538 = 18006 seconds  (Which is 5 hours and 6 sec behind me)

Any idea on what could be causing this?
I might be slightly less confused if it were +5 hours because that would be GMT.
But it's -5 hours which is Hawaii.
Also... why is the time correct in one format, but not in the other format?

---

## Additional info

I ran some more tests using additional MQL4 functions. I had them constantly pump out their results to my text file. I then quickly whipped together a BASH script to check out the results. I found the following:

Using this code in MT4

```
FileWrite(data_filehandle, "TimeDaylightSavings(): " + (string)TimeDaylightSavings());
FileWrite(data_filehandle,"TimeLocal(): "+(string)TimeLocal());
FileWrite(data_filehandle,"TimeGMTOffset(): "+(string)TimeGMTOffset());
FileWrite(data_filehandle,"TimeGMT(): "+(string)TimeGMT()+"\n\n");
```

Gave this output to my text file ( one fresh record about every second ):

```
TimeDaylightSavings(): 0
TimeLocal(): 1579601184
TimeGMTOffset(): 18000
TimeGMT(): 1579619184
```

I whipped up this BASH script to scan and check the results in real time:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'$'\b';

while true
do
        my_time=$(date);
        my_epoc=$(date '+%s');
        my_record="$( cat EURUSD_price_data.txt| dos2unix | tail -5 )";


        mt4_time_local=$( echo "$my_record" | grep -w 'TimeLocal' );
        echo "Reading line: $mt4_time_local";
        mt4_time_local=$(echo $mt4_time_local | awk '{print $2}' );

        echo "My time: $my_time  -- My epoc: $my_epoc -- MT4_TimeLocal epoc: $mt4_time_local -- Difference: $(( $my_epoc - $mt4_time_local ))";

        mt4_time_GMT=$( echo "$my_record" | grep -w 'TimeGMT' );
        echo "Reading line: $mt4_time_GMT";
        mt4_time_GMT=$(echo $mt4_time_GMT | awk '{print $2}' );
        echo "My time: $my_time  -- My epoc: $my_epoc -- MT4_TimeGMT epoc: $mt4_time_GMT -- Difference: $(( $my_epoc - $mt4_time_GMT ))";


        echo "";
        sleep 1;
done
```

and got this result:

```
Reading line: TimeLocal(): 1579601184
My time: Tue Jan 21 10:06:25 EST 2020  -- My epoc: 1579619185 -- MT4_TimeLocal epoc: 1579601184 -- Difference: 18001
Reading line: TimeGMT(): 1579619184
My time: Tue Jan 21 10:06:25 EST 2020  -- My epoc: 1579619185 -- MT4_TimeGMT epoc: 1579619184 -- Difference: 1
```

Now if I add '#property strict' to switch back to Date Time format I get:

```
TimeDaylightSavings(): 0
TimeLocal(): 2020.01.21 10:23:56
TimeGMTOffset(): 18000
TimeGMT(): 2020.01.21 15:23:56
```

My system time:

```
$ date
Tue Jan 21 10:23:57 EST 2020
```

---

## Conclusion

For some reason when getting epoc time TimeLocal() gives the wrong time (Hawaiian time for some reason ) , but surprisingly TimeGMT() gives the correct time, even though I am in the EST timezone.

Using the exact same code and set up, when getting the time in Date Time format ( using the '#property strict' directive ) the situation is reversed. TimeLocal() gives the correct time and TimeGMT() gives the wrong time ( but at least it gives correct GMT time )

Is this a bug in MT4, or is there something going on behind the scenes that I haven't fully understood yet?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *Any idea on what could be causing this?*

The **`#property strict`** is a compiler-phase kill-switch, which changes lots of details how the MQL4, syntactically correct, compositions will get understood in either { "*old*" | "*new*" }-fashion

> <sub>( **not reading** this part of the documentation **each time after** MT4 IDE **update** may and will surprise you, so better re-read it always after each and every update )</sub>

*"Old"*-MQL4 used a **`int32`** for `datetime` internal storage, *"New"*-MQL4.56789… uses `int64`, so any roll-overs are way farther.

```
FileWrite( data_filehandle, "sys_time:"
                          + (string)TimeLocal()                    // localhost-dependent
                          + "."
                          + StringFormat( "%06lu", usec_instance )
                          + ", sym:"
                          + (string)Symbol()
                          + ", tick_time:"
                          + (string)last_tick.time                 // Fx-QUOTE-dependent
                          + ", ask:"
                          + (string)last_tick.ask
                          + ", bid:"
                          + (string)last_tick.bid
                          );
```

See **`TimeGMT()`** and **`TimeGMTOffset()`** for other built-in options.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading, thinking and testing I have found the answer ( though I don't know what they were thinking when they did things this way ).

The issue is right here:

```
TimeDaylightSavings(): 0
TimeLocal(): 1579601184  <-- should be the same as TimeGMT(). Epoc does not respect timezone
TimeGMTOffset(): 18000
TimeGMT(): 1579619184
```

Unix epoc time is based on an event that happened on Jan 1st 1970 00:00 UTC.
It does not respect time zones. It is supposed to be the same for everyone on Earth at all times.

You can also see from the original problem that anytime I use the:

```
date '+%s'
```

command that my system gives me a correct Unix epoc which matches the output of TimeGMT() from MT4. So the problem is not my system.

However, above we can see that TimeLocal() is not treating the epoc the way that it should. It is adjusting the unix epoc in an attempt to compensate for my time zone. This behavior is probably how it accomplishes producing the correct time when it is displayed in Date Time format. The problem is that when it is asked to produce the time in epoc format it is still doing time zone conversions, which violates that very meaning of Unix epoc time.

So, the solution ( as far as I can tell ) is to simply use TimeGMT() anytime I want a correct Unix epoc. It seems pretty crazy that I have to specifically avoid using TimeLocal() in certain cases... but I guess that's just the way it is?